Passing double value to JSON string having a root header
I am trying to create a JSON string content by passing a double typed value (named time). My JSON content is also containing a root header object (named UserAddTime). I would like to add time in Minutes object.
double time = 60;
var content = new StringContent
        (@"{
            'UserAddTime':
            {
                'Minutes':"+time+",
                'TotalPrice':0.00,
                'IsTaxIncluded':false
            }
          }",
        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 

It doesn't allow me to add time like this:
'Minutes':"+time+",

And shows me the red line error content LOC:

I am trying this solution, but not able to get my expected results like:
{
    "UserAddTime" : {
        "Minutes" : 60,
        "TotalPrice" : 0.00,
        "IsTaxIncluded" : false
    }
}

Your any help will be really appreciated!

Instead of StringContent you can  narrow down to a JsonContent type, working directly with models and using factory method JsonContent.Create.

The correct thing todo is in the answer. YOu get the error here because after concatenation time you concatenate a new standard string. You can't simply have a line break in such a string. For example put a @ in front of that string just like you did for the first string here before the time variable. Then your compiler error should go but its still bad code ;) Use what's in the answer.

@Ralf That's not working.

Instead of constructing the JSON manually, you should look for constructing an object and then serialize via JSON library such as System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json.
using System.Text.Json;

double time = 60;
var body = new 
{
    UserAddTime = new
    {
        Minutes = time,
        TotalPrice = 0.00,
        IsTaxIncluded = false
    }
};

var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(body),
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


Does it create a root header object?

@SoftSol Try and see yourself.
